# error 111 connection refused, topology type :unknown

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to containerise an python-flask application which uses MongoDB as database.

the error that I am getting

[image: 1]

The error is same when whether I run the Dockerfile of project or the Docker-compose file.
It works fine when I run it on my machine locally.

My DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3


    
COPY requirements.txt ./
    
WORKDIR /

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install build-essential libdbus-glib-1-dev libgirepository1.0-dev -y
RUN apt-get install python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libcups2-dev -y
RUN apt install libgirepository1.0-dev -y


RUN pip install pycups
RUN pip install cmake
RUN pip install dbus-python
RUN pip install reportlab
RUN pip install PyGObject 

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

    
COPY . .

CMD ["python3","main.py"]
```

MY DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
version: '2.0'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  myapp:
    image: 'chatapp'
    networks:
      - app-tier
    links:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
```

I tried linking the two containers via --links but i am unable to figure out what actual problem is.

Comment: What's the actual error?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  If you can [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including the error message in plain text, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is trying to mongodb with localhost:27017.

For your app, localhost, is the container where the app is running.
To access the mingoDb container you must use the service name in your docker-compose.yaml.

In your case: mongodb.
So the connection to the db should be: mongodb:27017.

To access mongodb directly from your host macchine you use localhost:27018. In this case localhost refers to your hostsystem (your pc).

Your docker-compose is a bit obsolete. You can update it like so:

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  myapp: // this is a service name
    image: 'chatapp'
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb: // this is the servicename to connect from the app container
    image: 'mongo'
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
```

You can remove also allowempty password.

Comment: No that gives the same error. and u removed "--links" so ... i dont understand how will two containers communicate now ??

Comment: Links is obsolete you dont need it anymore. Post your connection string, maybe also there is something wrong.

Comment: import pymongo
my_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")


is this u r talking about.? please correct me if m wrong, I am new to these technologies.

Comment: That what i told you in my answer not localhost:27017 but mongodb:27017. From the docker point of view localhost refers to each container itself. To connect to a different container, use just the servicename. mongodb in your case as you have called the service in your docker compose file.

Comment: I wrote a comment in the answer to show you were the service name is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped I understood what I was doing wrong ! Thank you so much. @Ralle